# If $M$ is a maximal ideal in $C^{\ast}X)$, and $Z[M]$ is a $z$-filter ,is $Z[M]$ a $z$-ultrafilter?

Tags: general-topology, ideals, filters

Let $ X$ be a topological space. The set $C(X)$ is all continuous, real valued functions on $X$, so that $C(X) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{X}$.

$C^\ast(X) = \{ f \in C(X) \mid  f \text{ is bounded }\}$.

**A nonempty subfamily  $\mathcal{F}$ of $Z(X)$  is called $z$-filter on   $X$  provided that:**

1: $  \emptyset \notin \mathcal{F}$

2: If $z_{1} , z_{2} \in \mathcal{F}$  , then $z_{1} \cap z_{2} \in \mathcal{F}$

3:  If $ z \in \mathcal{F} , z_{2} \in Z(X) , z_{2} \supset z$ , then $ z_{2} \in \mathbb{F}$

The family $Z[ C(X)] =Z(X) =\{ Z(f) : f \in C(X) \}$ is all zero-sets in $X$. (where $Z(f) = \{ x \in X : f(x) = 0 \} $)

If $I$ is an ideal in $C(X)$, the  $Z[I]=\{ Z(f) : f \in I \}$ is a $z$-filter.

By a $z$-ultrafilter on $X$ is meant a maximal $z$- filter, i.e one not properly contained in any other $z$-filter.

**So, my question is:**

If $M$ is a maximal ideal in $C^\ast(X)$, and $Z[M]$ is a $z$-filter, is $Z[M]$ a $z$-ultrafilter?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is true and a minor modification of the same ideas for all of $C(X)$:

> **Lemma** If $\mathcal{F}$ is a $z$-filter, the set $Z^{-1}[\mathcal{F}]=\{f \in C^\ast(X): Z(f) \in \mathcal{F}\}$ is an ideal in $C^\ast(X)$.

Proof: Suppose that $f,g \in Z^{-1}[\mathcal{F}]$. Then $Z(f), Z(g) \in \mathcal{F}$ and note that $Z(f) \cap Z(g) \subseteq Z(f-g)$, and from the properties of a $z$-filter it follows that $Z(f-g) \in \mathcal{F}$, so that by definiton, $f-g \in Z^{-1}[\mathcal{F}]$. So $Z^{-1}[\mathcal{F}]$ is a subgroup of $C^\ast(X)$ and if $h \in C^\ast(X)$ then $Z(f) \subseteq Z(fh)$, so that again $Z(fh) \in\mathcal{F}$ and so $fh \in Z^{-1}[\mathcal{F}]$, so $Z^{-1}[\mathcal{F}]$ is also closed under multiplciation by arbitary members from $C^\ast(X)$. Finally $Z^{-1}[\mathcal{F}]$ is a proper filter, as $\emptyset \notin \mathcal{F}$, and $\emptyset = Z(f)$ iff $f$ is a unit.

Now suppose that $M$ is a maximal ideal in $C^\ast(X)$ and $Z[M]$ is a $z$-filter (this is automatic for $C(X)$ but maybe not for $C^\ast(X)$?). Then $Z[M]$ is a $z$-ultrafilter:

Suppose that $\mathcal{F}$ is a $z$-filter such that $Z[M] \subseteq \mathcal{F}$.

> **Claim** $Z^{-1}[Z[M]] = M$.

This is clear from maximality, as by definition $M \subseteq Z^{-1}[Z[M]]$ and when $Z[M]$ is a $z$-filter, $Z^{-1}[Z[M]]$ is an ideal in $C^\ast(X)$ by the lemma.

Now $Z^{-1}[\mathcal{F}]$ is also an ideal (same lemma) and it contains $M$ (as $f \in M$ implies $Z(f) \in Z[M]$, so $Z(f) \in \mathcal{F}$ and thus $f \in Z^{-1}[\mathcal{F}]$). So by maximality of $M$ again, $$Z^{-1}[\mathcal{F}] = M$$

So now, if $F \in \mathcal{F}$, this means that $F = Z(f)$ for some $f \in C^\ast(X)$ (as $Z(X) = \{Z(f): f \in C(X)\} = \{Z(f) : f \in C^\ast(X)\}$ and $\mathcal{F} \subseteq Z(X)$). So $f \in Z^{-1}[\mathcal{F}]$ and so $f \in M$ and hence $F = Z(f) \in Z[M]$. Conclusion:

$$\mathcal{F} \subseteq Z[M]$$

and thus $Z[M]$ is a $z$-ultrafilter.